# Display the helper text when TextField focused in Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want the error message isn't shown until a user clicks on TextField. Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect }               from 'react';
import { TextField, Grid, Button }                  from '@material-ui/core';

const ReplyToComment = () => {

    const [replyContent, setReplyContent] = useState();
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(replyContent) {
            if(replyContent.length > 7){
                setErrorMessage([]);
            } else {
                setErrorMessage(["Your answer is too short"])
            }
        } else {
            setErrorMessage(["answer field can not empty"])
        }
    }, [replyContent]);

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setReplyContent(event.target.value)
    };
    
    const handleSubmit = async () => {
    console.log("************")
    };

    return (
        <Grid container  spacing={4} alignItems="center" justify="center" >
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <TextField
                    value={replyContent}
                    name="reply"
                    fullWidth
                    required
                    error={Boolean(errorMessage.length)}
                    multiline
                    label="answer"
                    helperText={errorMessage[0]}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    />
            </Grid>
            <Button onClick={handleSubmit} variant="contained" color="primary" disabled={Boolean(errorMessage.length)}>add</Button>
        </Grid>
    );
}
 
export default ReplyToComment;
```

This way, the error message is shown before a user any action, but I want the error message isn't shown until a user clicks on TextField.

[Try it on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-sun-80dhg?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easiest solution would be to use a flag which holds the information about the clicked (touched) state for the TextField.

Example:

```
const ReplyToComment = () => {

    const [replyContent, setReplyContent] = useState();
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState([]);
    const [touched, setTouched] = useState(false);

    const handleTouch = () => {
     setTouched(true);
    };

    // ...

    return (
        <Grid container  spacing={4} alignItems="center" justify="center" >
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <TextField
                    value={replyContent}
                    name="reply"
                    fullWidth
                    required
                    onFocus={handleTouch}
                    error={touched && Boolean(errorMessage.length)}
                    multiline
                    label="answer"
                    helperText={touched && errorMessage[0]}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    />
            </Grid>
            <Button onClick={handleSubmit} variant="contained" color="primary" disabled={Boolean(errorMessage.length)}>add</Button>
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

I have set the value on `onFocus` but it is totally up to you when you would want the TextField to be classified as touched (`onBlur`, `onClick`)